# How to assign a running value to a row depending on some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I'm trying to give a certain number of point to my row depending on some condition, I can't figure out how to write it.

For a given Id, FormatCode and Price I want to give the value 1.
For subsequent rows, for the same Id and Price, if the FormatCode is a multiple of a previous row with the same Id and price, I want to give the same value.

For instance :

`00010405, 100, 0.3218 = 1`

`00010405, 400, 0.3218 = 1` (400 % 100 = 0)

`00010405, 500, 0.3126 = 2` (500 % 100 = 0, but the price is different)

`00010405, 1000, 0.3126 = 2` (1000 % 500 and 1000 % 100 = 0, but the price of the format code 100 is different, hence it will take the value 2 because it has the same price)

| Id | Format Code | Price | Value | Row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00010405 | 100 | 0.3218 | 1 | 1 |
| 00010405 | 400 | 0.3218 | 1 | 2 |
| 00010405 | 500 | 0.3126 | 2 | 3 |
| 00010405 | 1000 | 0.3126 | 2 | 4 |

```
SELECT
   Id,
   FormatCode,
   Price,
   Value,
   ROW_NUMER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY Id
      ORDER BY FormatCode
   )
FROM Table
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: What is logic for the 4th row? is it `1000 % 500` or `1000 % 100`? Why? There's really not enough information for us to do more than guess what your logic is beyond these 3 vague examples.

Comment: You state in the question *"For subsequent rows, for the same Id and Price, if the FormatCode is a multiple of a previous row"*, however, for when `FormatCode` has a value of `500` the previous row has a value of `400` yet your example expression states `100` is the comparison: *"(500 % 100 = 0, but the price is different)"*. Does "A previous row", mean *any* of them? If so, why not state *"(500 % 400 = 100 however, 500 % 100 = 0, but the price is different)"* so that that condition is clear?

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh the expected output is as in the table shown in the question

Comment: @Larnu the forth row is 1000 % 500 because the price is the same as the format code 500, I have edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: So why is it not 500 % 400%? There's a lack of consistency here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to prioritise formatCode multiplier over price.
Instead of `ROW_NUMBER` you should take a look at `DENSE_RANK`.

The description is still a bit unclear to me, but if I understood it correctly here is a working example:

```
--Setup some sample data

drop table if exists #tmp

select *
into #tmp
from (values 
('00010405',100, 0.3218 ),
('00010405',400, 0.3218 ),
('00010405',500, 0.3126 ),
('00010405',1000, 0.3126 ),
('00010405',1333, 0.3126 ),--not a multiple
('00010405',2666, 0.3126 )--multiple of previous row
) as tab(id, formatcode, price)

--Make the calculation
select 
    t.id,
    t.formatcode,
    t.price,
    DENSE_RANK() over(partition by id order by minMulti.formatCodeMin_multiplier, t.price) as Value
from #tmp t
cross apply(
    select min(formatCode) as formatCodeMin_multiplier
    from #tmp t2
    where t.id = t2.id and t.price = t2.price
    and t.formatcode % t2.formatcode = 0
) as minMulti
order by id, formatcode
```

The trick is to find the formatcode with the lowest value where the current row's value is a multiplier of.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed... dense_rank